# Emacs Melpa and Marmalade

Tags: emacs, package-management

Does it make sense to include both Melpa and Marmalade package repositories with emacs HEAD.

And if so, what is the best way to ensure that one is using the latest and/or correct package, when many packages will be confusingly listed in both.

I'm using:

```
GNU Emacs 25.0.50.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0, NS appkit-1265.21 Version 10.9.5 (Build 13F34)) of 2014-10-18
```

When I do package-list-packages, many packages are duplicated.

Comment: If some of the packages offered are different, then you probably want both.  I personally keep the configuration commented out until I actually want to install something.

Comment: Different users want different things. It is not nonsense to include both. Whether that makes sense for a given user is up to that user.

Comment: If your question is really about how to deal with duplicate packages when using multiple repositories, then ask that.

Comment: Given a package is in both Melpa and Marmalade (one with version number and one with date), which one is preferable generally? It's confusing to have duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO [this answer on emacs.SE](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/10501/421) answers your question by explaining the differences between ELPA, MELPA, and Marmelade, including some words on the overlap between the three.

Comment: Sounds like Melpa + Gnu Elpa, and not using Marmalade,is the way to go. Any easy way to convert?